# Laravel + SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, laravel-4

I was working on a Laravel 4.2 application (Xampp 3.2.1 / PHP 5.6.8 / Windows 7)
I was able to create a prototype with database as MySQL and everything was good. 
My manager wants me to change my database to MS SQL.

Now I tried to find solution online and did few things like enabling

```
extension=php_mssql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

in my php.ini files

But When I look at my phpinfo(), I see  "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql"
Can anyone please help me here, how can fix this ?

Comment: Plz makesure you have modified correct php.ini and if php_mssql.dll enabled in php.ini is present in your extension dir.

Comment: I can't tell you what your issue is. However, you can always use the [`sqlsrv`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) extension from Microsoft (version 3.2).